# Flattening a graph

Tags: graph, tree

I have been given a problem to solve that I am fairly certain its insoluble.

For a system I am working in I need to take piece of branching logic (graph) and translate it to a linear path(flatten it), without node repeats. Given a tree I know that I can do this.

The rules are that the path must be traversed in order, but can 'skip' any panel if some condition is met.

Given the tree:

> A > B > C
>
> &&
>
> A > D > E

Our tree can be flattened to:

> A > B > C > D > E

So in this case B and C share the same conditional, and D, and E have the inverse of that condition. Thus if B is met so is C, but D and E will be skipped. Conversely, if B is not met, B and C are skipped, but D and E aren't.

So far, so simple. I am fairly convinced this is true for any tree. The problem I have is that the objects I have been given to flatten are graphs, and contain simple cycles, and closed walks.

After that huge preamble my questions are:
Am I right in stating that it is impossible to guarantee that such a graph can be flattened?
I know that closed walks cannot follow my rules (by virtue of returning to a node), but are there any other rules that describe a 'flatten-able' graph versus a 'non-flatten-able' one?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a directed graph, then the graph can be flattened if there are no directed cycles.

There is a handy library available [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) which will provide the necessary methods to determine if there is a cycle presnet as well a TopologicalOrderIterator which will perform the flattening as well.

Using the graph library and the example above this code will show an exmaple of how to do it.

```
DirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> graph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

graph.addVertex("A");
graph.addVertex("B");
graph.addVertex("C");
graph.addVertex("D");
graph.addVertex("E");

// A > B
graph.addEdge("A", "B");

// B > C
graph.addEdge("B", "C");

// A > D
graph.addEdge("A", "D");

// D > E
graph.addEdge("D", "E");

// Uncomment the following line to create a cyclic graph.
//graph.addEdge("E", "D");

CycleDetector<String, DefaultEdge> cycleDector = new CycleDetector<String, DefaultEdge>(graph);

if (cycleDector.detectCycles()) {
    System.err.println("Cyclic graph");
} else {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Create topological order iterator
    for (TopologicalOrderIterator<String, DefaultEdge> iter = new TopologicalOrderIterator<String, DefaultEdge>(
        graph); iter.hasNext();) {
    String vertex = iter.next();

    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(" > ");
    }

    sb.append(vertex);
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Sample output with the cycle disabled.

> A > B > D > C > E